# Couldn't reserve memory though there's space

Tags: windows-7, memory, memory-limit

I am trying to use Weka (http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) on a 64-bit Windows 7 system which is by nature very memory bound. Problem is that my PC has 8GB RAM and my task manager says that only 1.5 are allocated. Even so, when I try to run Weka which would supposedly use only 3 of these GB, it fails with the following error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 3072000KB object heap
```

Ideas?

Comment: Are you running 32- or 64-bit Windows 7?

Comment: 32 bit, sorry will edit

Comment: That's part of your problem: only 4GB of your memory is addressable.

Comment: I'm sorry had to re-check that, it's actually 64. Sorry again, my bad

Comment: The error message indicates that the object heap required 300MB: where did your 3GB requirement come from?

Comment: I actually missed a 0 since I had to copy this by hand for reasons that are no worth explaining. Edited that too

Comment: I'm wondering if your Java installation might be 32-bit. If so, you need to be careful about the amount of memory allocated to it, eg if you allocate 6GB, a 32-bit application will see only 2GB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Error occurred during initialization of VM

> Could not reserve enough space for 3072000KB object heap

You need to increase the **maximum heap size** of the JVM.

Try:

```
java -Xmx4g ...
```

Note:

- You will also need to make sure you have a 64bit version of the JVM installed.

---

#### OutOfMemoryException

> Most Java virtual machines only allocate a certain maximum amount of memory to run Java programs. Usually this is much less than the amount of RAM in your computer. However, you can extend the memory available for the virtual machine by setting appropriate options. With Sun's JDK, for example, you can use
>
> `java -Xmx512m ...`
>
> to set the maximum Java heap size to 512MB. You can use `-Xmx2g` to set it to 2GB.
>
> For more information about these options, follow this [link](http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/VMOptions.html).
>
> Note:
>
> Do not use the `-Xms` parameter as well, as this will lead quickly
>   to an OutOfMemoryException.
>
> If you are using WEKA under Windows and start WEKA from the Start Menu, check out the [Invocation](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Java+Virtual+Machine#Invocation) section of the [Java Virtual Machine](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Java+Virtual+Machine) article, it explains what files you have to edit in order to give WEKA more memory (RunWEKA.bat or RunWEKA.ini, depending on your version).
>
> But please have in mind, that your hardware architecture and/or operating system will limit the amount of memory you can allocate (see the 32-bit and 64-bit sections of the Java Virtual Machine article).

Source [OutOfMemoryException](http://weka.wikispaces.com/OutOfMemoryException)

---

#### Can I check how much memory is available for WEKA?

> You can easily check, how much memory WEKA can use (this depends on
>   the maximum heap size the Java Virtual Machine was started with).
>
> 1. developer version
>
>    - start the SimpleCLI
>    - run the following command:
>    - java weka.core.SystemInfo
>    - the property memory.max lists the maximum amount of memory available to WEKA
> 2. book version (and developer version)
>
>    - start the Explorer
>    - right-click in the log panel
>    - select Memory information to output the information to the log
>
> In case you should run into an OutOfMemoryException, you will have to
>   increase the maximum heap size. How much you can allocate, depends
>   heavily on the operating system and the underlying hardware (see
>   sections 32-Bit and 64-Bit of the [Java Virtual Machine](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Java+Virtual+Machine) article).
>   Also, have a look at the [OutOfMemoryException](http://weka.wikispaces.com/OutOfMemoryException) section further
>   down.

Source [Can I check how much memory is available for WEKA?](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Can+I+check+how+much+memory+is+available+for+WEKA%3F)

---

#### Further Reading

- http://weka.wikispaces.com/Frequently+Asked+Questions

Comment: Note that when Task Manager says "my PC has 8GB RAM and my task manager says that only 1.5 are allocated", that's talking about **physical memory** - RAM. When the Java VM complains about allocating space, that's talking about **virtual** memory. You can of course use a lot more virtual memory than you have RAM, but in order to prevent using up all of your commit limit with pre-allocated heap that your particular Java app might not use, the Java VM has a default limit to how much it will allocate.